# Convergence in measure and boundedness imply convergence in integral

Tags: real-analysis

This question comes from Royden's Real Analysis, 3rd edition.

The question states: use Proposition 14 to prove directly that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ in measure and if there is an integrable function $g$ such that for all $n$ we have $|f_n| \leq g$, then $\int |f_n - f| \rightarrow 0$.

Proposition 14 states: if $f$ is a nonnegative function that is integrable over a set $E$, then for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for every set $A \subset E$, $ m(A) < \delta$ implies that $\int_A f < \epsilon$.

I'm trying to solve this problem but I just don't see the connection between the question being asked and the proposition I'm supposed to use.  The proposition shows that the integral of $f$ over small sets is small, but as far as I can tell it tells us nothing about the integral over the whole set.

Any guidance here is appreciated.